# Three.js / jquery: controls and animation inside a div

Tags: jquery, three.js, requestanimationframe

I've put the renderer domElement inside a div called plot_area:

```
var container;
var camera, controls, scene, renderer;          
var numPoints, scale = 3;
init();
animate();

function init() {
    numPoints = document.getElementById('inputNumPoints').value;
    container = document.getElementById('plot_area');

    renderer = initRenderer(container);
    camera = initCamera();
    scene = initScene();            
    controls = initControls(camera, container, render);

    drawAxes(scale, 0x444444, scene);
}

function animate() {            
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
}

function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Here are the initializers (mostly standard Three.js):

```
function initRenderer(container) {
    var renderer;
    if (Detector.webgl)
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    else if (Detector.canvas)
        renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    else
        Detector.addGetCanvasMessage();

    renderer.setSize(800, 800);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    return renderer;
};

function initCamera() {
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 1, 1, 500);
    camera.position.set(0, -10, 0);
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

    return camera;
};

function initScene() {
    return new THREE.Scene();
};

function initControls(camera, container, renderFunc) {
    var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, container);
    controls.addEventListener('change', renderFunc);

    return controls;
};
```

And attached the controls to the very same div. Now when trying to rotate or pan (zooming is fine, though), div appears completely blank. Once I use the whole document as the scope for controls, everything works just fine.

I suspected there might (but shouldn't) have been a global/local name conflict, but the problem wasn't solved by renaming all the `init*` function parameters. Another guess was that some kind of copy constructor is called at return, so that the objects returned from `init*` are not really related to anything. (Yes, I'm no expert on js). Maybe, some trouble with request animation frame not working when out of focus?

Some examples: [document-scoped controls](http://vmathtest.p.ht/levels.html), [div-scoped controls](http://vmathtest.p.ht/derivative.html).

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3778
This could be a bug in the current OrbitControls

Comment: @GuyGood weird, TrackballControls won't work at all.

Comment: Oh, I've found my account keys. Fixed, bug in r66.